# Computing summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to evaluate the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{2^n}-3^{-2^n}}$$ I have tried to put it into partial fractions but it doesn't seem to telescope. Does anyone have any ideas?

According to Wolfram, the answer is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: I can prove that it converges. I just don't know how to evaluate it.

Comment: Prove by induction that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{3^{2^n}- 3^{-2^n}} = \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{3^{2^{N+1}}-1}.$$

Comment: How did you know that this was the thing to do?

Comment: I started computing the sum of the first three terms, it became obvious then. It's perhaps easier to find if you do it generically, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^{2^n}-a^{-2^n}}.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strategy: find an expression that can be replaced by a geometric series. Here,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{2^n}-3^{-2^n}} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-2^n} \frac{1}{1-3^{-2^{n+1}}} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-2^n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-2^{n+1}k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-2^n(2k+1)}.
\end{align*}
All the exponents are even, and every even number $2m$ can be written uniquely as $2m=2^n(2k+1)$ where $n\ge1,k\ge0$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-2^n(2k+1)} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty 3^{-2m} = \frac{1/9}{1-1/9} = \frac18
$$
(another geometric series).

Answer (score 3):

Greg Martin's answer is very concise and elegant. Interesting to know that $2^n(2k+1)$ cycles through all even numbers.

Here's my attempt - a much less elegant one. Partial fractions comes in handy but surprisingly not for telescoping.

[image]